# Why is jquery progressbar giving the following error: Object [object Object] has no method 'progressbar'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add a progressBar to my site. I have looked at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar and written the following code:

```
<div>
<h2>@Model.First().Category.category_name</h2>
<div id="progressBar"></div> 
</div>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#progressBar").progressbar({ value: 37 });

}
```

But Chrome displays the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'progressbar'
```

I am using

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can i fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: could it be your include statement? have you tried using the src attribute the normal way?

Comment: Have you actually included jQuery UI as well?

Comment: I forgot to add the jQuery UI. I have now added it, and i get no errors. But the the progress bar is not there either :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section "Basic overview: using jQuery UI on a web page" in the [JQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started). I suspect that you don't have all the includes you need. Also check your paths.

Comment: I forgot to include both UI and CSS